# Репозитории по DDD

Tags: php, repository, ddd

Я не могу понять, как правильно реализовать по DDD связанные репозитории.
Ниже синтетический пример, мне приходится писать два запроса к БД, тогда как можно было бы ограничится одним?

Если бы связь была бы многие-ко-многим, то необходимо(как верно?) писать еще и репозиторий для связи user_roles?

Например:

```
Class UserRepository
{

    public function findOne($id)
    {
        ..... $sql_query...
        $query = "select *, role_id from users where user_id = :id";

    }

}

Class RoleRepository
{

    public function findOne($id)
    {
        $query = "select * from roles where role_id = :id";
    }
}

Class UserService 
{

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOne($id);

        $role = $this->roleRepository->findOne($user['role_id']);

        $data = new User($user);
        $data->setRole($role);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: В DDD тебе нужно агрегировать сущности и сохранять корневой агрегат. Для поиска и выборки ты можешь в любом репозитории обращаться с любой таблице в БД. Особенно если у них связь. Это не анти паттерн.

Comment: то есть допустим я создам репозиторий для агрегата UserRolesRepository, но в тех случаях когда мне нужны только пользователи я создам UserRepository, но тогда у меня будет дублироваться запрос, и допустим я захочу делать выборку только активных пользователей, мне придется добавлять в два репозитория это условие. Мне кажется это не совсем верно, или я не что-то не так понял?

Comment: Не надо таким бредом заниматься. 
UserRepository у тебя сразу достает пользователя с ролью они должны быть связаны внешними ключами, то есть напрямую делает запрос. То есть setRole у тебя происходит внутри репозитория, а не сервиса. В твоем примере. Пишешь Join запрос и все работает. И создание сущности, нужно через рефлексию делать. В ДДД сеттеры это антипаттерн

Comment: если коротко, то любой репозитории может работать с любыми таблицами из базы. Не важно к какой сущности он относиться, что сущности нужно, то он и достает. Иначе будут проблемы, что в сервис нужно будет инжектить по 50 репозиториев и собирать их в сущности. Вообще не ответственность сервиса.

Comment: насчет сервиса согласен, но я же могу из репозитория обращаться в другие репозитории, иначе текущий репозиторий  превратиться в "Божественный объект"